# How to get the capacity and free space of a directory which has another mount in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos

For example, the dir "/app/source"
There is an 100GB filesystem mount on "/"
So when I use "df /app/source" I can get the capacity is 100GB.
Then there is a dir "/app/source/video" and an 100GB filesystem mount on it.
Is there any easy way to get the real capacity (200GB) of "/app/source" ?

Answer (score 0):

`/app/source` don't have a capacity of 200G, thus you cannot expect to see it. It's "real" capacity is 100G as the underlying disk capacity is 100G. If you think it has a capacity of 200G, then you expect to be able to store 200G of data in `/app/source` but you cannot ! You can store 100G in `/app/source` and 100G in `/app/source/video`

Comment: I want to get a number that merge two capacity?

Comment: But when I think deeply, I found it seems a wrong way to solve my problem.

Comment: If your goal is to report somewhere that you have a 200G disk/volume/directory then yes, it's probably a bad idea because you haven't 200G available

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you would like to really merge the capacity of both partitions, for this you could use LVM.

Trying to merge only the reported numbers, which you could do with a simple script or alias (see below), would give you bad information and then you may try to add files on a full partition.

If at the end you still need the added total, maybe something like this can help:

```
# df -h --total /app/source /app/source/video | grep total | awk -F" " '{print $2}'
```